# data when I concatenate with predictions

Tags: python, machine-learning, tkinter

I have a Tkinter GUI  that runs a Logistic Reg. the app has two button; One for getting the file and a second to make predictions. My program is built this way: 
The top contains the whole sklearn way to do things til the data are fitted. Then the second part contains the my Tkinter GUI.
My prediction button issues a file containing the categorical values I did not want and the predictions themselves.
The only problem is when file is issued, the top of is almost empty although I have the predictions and the prediction function is producing exactly what I want when used without the GUI. Here is what the issued looks like:

```
 X1   X2  X3  Preds
                0
                1
                1
                0
 xx   xx   xx
 xx   xx   xx
 xx   xx   xx
 xx   xx   xx
```

Here is what I have done:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.geometry('600x450')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.configure(background='white')

root.title('First ML GUI')
label1= Label(root,text='ML APP',bg= 'white')
label1.config(font=('Courier',20, 'bold'))
label1.place(x=100, y=30)

def catch_file():
# getting my file
root.filename=filedialog.askopenfilename()

btn_getfile=Button(root, text='Load_File', command=lambda:catch_file())
btn_getfile.pack()
btn_getfile.place(x=265,y=120)
#on_click_pred=Label(root, textvariable=msg2)

### Here is the Pred button##############

btn_predict=Button(root, text='PREDS', 
command=lambda:predictor(root.filename))
btn_predict.pack()
btn_predict.place(x=450,y=200)
on_click_pred=Label(root, textvariable=msg2)
on_click_pred.place(x=360,y=150)

def predictor(file)

   data=pd.read_csv(file)

   data=data.dropna()
   categorical=data[['A1','A2','A3']]
   numerical=data.select_dtypes(include=['number'])
   numerical=numerical[['X1','X2','X3']]
   numerical=sc.transform(numerical)
   pred=lr.predict(numerical)
   pred_df=pd.DataFrame(pred, columns=['Preds'])
   report=pd.concat([categorical,pred_df], axis=1)
   report.to_csv('report.csv')

root.mainloop()
```

So in one word, the first part of the issued file only contained the predictions and the second part all the data I need but the preds column is now empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need not `concat`, you can just save the predictions as a new column.

```
numerical['Preds'] = pred
numerical.to_csv('report.csv')
```

Comment: thanks Jeril, I still do not know why its happening. Plus its only giving me less rows now

Comment: Sorry, I have revised the solution, can you please check now.